# Is it is possible to use both google signin and facebook signin at a same time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

*flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
google_sign_in: ^4.4.4*

I got the error while trying to use both facebook signin and google signin at a same time.

I need to know **Is it is possible to use both google signin and facebook signin at a same time in flutter?**

**I/flutter (26605): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)**

Comment: Are you using firebase?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase, you can do it like this:

add this dependencies to the pubspec.yaml file and run "flutter pub get" command

```
flutter_facebook_auth: "^1.0.0"
google_sign_in: "^4.5.1"
```

For Google sign in:

```
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
// Trigger the authentication flow
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

// Obtain the auth details from the request
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

// Create a new credential
final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

// Once signed in, return the UserCredential
return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```

For facebook:

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';

Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook() async {
// Trigger the sign-in flow
final AccessToken result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

// Create a credential from the access token
final facebookAuthCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.token);

// Once signed in, return the UserCredential
return await
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
}
```

If the problem persists maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28225) has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the valueable response , I tried this to if i use only one plugin it works fine but when i add both at a time , It shows     :                 
            MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)                                                                                I think ,This is because of package conflit error can you help me  to solve this

Comment: I added a link to a github issue with a similar problem to yours, please check it out.